# Kendo MVC UI Grid - Display empty string as Date for null or default date (1900-01-01 00:00:00.000)

Tags: datetime, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Two date columns in Grid and I am trying to set empty string for null or default date.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.DateCreated).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}").Filterable(false).Width(120);
columns.Bound(p => p.LastLogIn).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}").Filterable(false).Width(120);
```

Both fields are nullable in Model class.

```
public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastLogIn { get; set; }
```

In SQL Server table, both columns are `DATETIME` but values are

```
DateCreated = 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
LasLogIn = NULL
```

Values in debug mode,

[image]

But Grid displays empty string for `LastLogIn`, 31/12/1899 for `DateCreated`

[image]

So I added `ClientTemplate` to `DateCreated` to format the date

```
columns.Bound(p => p.DateCreated).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}").Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("#=formatDate(DateCreated)#").Width(120);
```

CASE 1 : 
As it displays 31/12/1899, modified the function in https://www.telerik.com/forums/date-clienttemplate-and-editortemplatename-for-nullable-or-0-dates

```
function formatDate(_date) {
    console.log("Input " + _date);
    var formated1900 = kendo.format("{0:d}", new Date(1900, 0, 1));
    console.log("formated1900 " + formated1900);
    var formated1899 = kendo.format("{0:d}", new Date(1899, 12, 31));
    console.log("formated1899 " + formated1899);
    var formatedDate = kendo.format("{0:d}", _date);
    console.log("formated Input " + formatedDate);
    if (formated1900 == formatedDate || formated1899 == formatedDate) {
        console.log("True " + formatedDate);
        return "";
    }
    else {
        console.log("False " + formatedDate);
        return kendo.format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", _date);
    }
}
```

Console output for CASE 1

```
Input Sun Dec 31 1899 22:55:25 GMT+0655 (Singapore Standard Time)
formated1900 1/1/1900
formated1899 1/31/1900
formated Input 12/31/1899
False 12/31/1899
```

CASE 2
As it formats to 1/31/1900, I modified the function again as

```
function formatDate(_date) {
    console.log("Input " + _date);
    var formated1900 = kendo.format("{0:d}", new Date(1900, 0, 1));
    console.log("formated1900 " + formated1900);
    var formated1899 = kendo.format("{0:d}", new Date(1900, 1, 31));
    console.log("formated1899 " + formated1899);
    var formatedDate = kendo.format("{0:d}", _date);
    console.log("formated Input " + formatedDate);
    if (formated1900 == formatedDate || formated1899 == formatedDate) {
        console.log("True " + formatedDate);
        return "";
    }
    else {
        console.log("False " + formatedDate);
        return kendo.format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", _date);
    }
}
```

Console output for CASE 2

```
Input Sun Dec 31 1899 22:55:25 GMT+0655 (Singapore Standard Time)
formated1900 1/1/1900
formated1899 3/3/1900
formated Input 12/31/1899
False 12/31/1899
```

As `kendo.format` returns different date, not able to set empty string for `DateCreated`.

Any other approach to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You're using both Format and ClientTemplate, I think only one can be used at a time.
Use the template and do _date === null ? '' : kendo.format(...

Comment: Thanks, I removed Format. But still it shows 12/31/1899 for DateCreated

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow such a long bug on top of my other work. Can you briefly summarize that it shows X for input Y instead of Z?

Comment: I understand. In DB the date is 1900-01-01 but grid shows 12/31/1899. For time being I solved it by validating _date == "Sun Dec 31 1899 22:55:25 GMT+0655 (Singapore Standard Time)" in formatDate()

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with the EditorTemplate of datepicker

```js
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("Name")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%", data_format = "dd-MMM-yyyy" })
              .Events(e =>
                           {
                                e.Change("ChangeFunction");
                            }
                       )
               )
```

please try to use client template  get more clarified solution

Comment: My question is related to data binding not editing.